# How to write data to excel in MATLAB in next columns when each time program executes having the previous results saved in previous columns

Tags: matlab

```
function []=calculate(a,b,c,d)

 calculation(1)=a*b;
 calculation(2)=a+b+c+d;
 calculation(3)=a*b*c*d;
 calculation(4)=(a+b)-(c+d);
 calculation = calculation';  %transpose of calculation array

 excelfile= 'test.xlsx';
 xlswrite(excelfile,calculation,'C4');

end
```

My actual code consists of a function that accepts 5 arguments and returns 14 values in an array similar to the code posted here. My problem is that each time I run the program which has the `calculate()` function called, it writes the data into test.xlsx file at column C starting from row4, but it overwrites the previously calculated data stored from C4. I want that when the 2nd time the main program is run the data should be written from column D and row4, for the third time to E4 and so on. Please help me with a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can pass a variable, that counts the amount of columns written, you can proceed like this:

```
function [] = calculate(a,b,c,d,counter)

stringvect = ('A':'Z');
posColumn = [stringvect(counter) '4'];

calculation(1)=a*b;
calculation(2)=a+b+c+d;
calculation(3)=a*b*c*d;
calculation(4)=(a+b)-(c+d);
calculation = calculation';  %transpose of calculation array

excelfile = 'test.xlsx';
xlswrite(excelfile,calculation,posColumn);

end
```

In case you want to have more than 26 columns you should simply add an if else to determine whether to add another letter or not.

If you can't use a counter, just write a response.

I hope this helps, cheers Pablo